# Best practice for id_token vs. access_token use in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, oauth-2.0, openid

Consider a restapi backend consisting of AWS-ApiGateway and -Lambda.

After successful oauth2 authentication, AWS Cognito returns both an `access_token` and an `id_token` to the client in the code authorization grant flow.

During API calls, the lambda function needs to know the email address of the authenticated client, so I basically have two choices:

1. Send the `id_token` in the `Authorization` header which is validated by the ApiGateway and passed to the Lambda. Let Lambda decrypt the `id_token` and access the email address contained in it.
2. Send the `access_token` in the `Authorization` header which is validated by the ApiGateway with `scope=openid email` and passed to the Lambda. Let Lambda make a `GET` call to the `/oauth2/userinfo` endpoint with the **access_token** in the `Authorization` header to obtain email address.

Which of both is best practice? Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good question:

- Access tokens are designed to be short lived API credentials, containing scopes / claims etc
- Id tokens have a different role, to provide proof of authentication to a client, as in my [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/25/id-tokens/)

However, if you are using AWS Cognito then there is a vendor limitation that access tokens cannot be customised - eg to include email address.

So it can be common for an API or a Gateway to do more work when a token is first received - eg to look up user info or claims from other sources - then cache them for subsequent requests with the same access token.

That is, option 2 is preferred, rather than using an id token in an unnatural way.

For further info on this design pattern see:

- [Claims Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/)
- [Sample Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authorizer.ts)

Comment: Why AWS Cognito decided to not include the email claim as part of the access token is beyond me. At the least they should provide it as an option to include it.

Comment: The lack of support for claims handling in access tokens is not good. You can get the email by sending the access token to the user info endpoint though.

Comment: True, but the workarounds (calling user info endpoint, or implement your own backend email fields etc) defeats one of the benefits of using tokens i.e. not having to do DB lookups or cache lookups for each API interaction if you rely on email field. But I agree at least you can get around it.